# jquery fadeToggle with variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fadeToggle an image using the following HTML code

```
<img src="/images/guideknap.png" style="position: absolute; top:285px; left:83px; z-index:1;" name="rb-b-help" onclick="HelpToggle(this.name)">    
<div id='rb-b-help' ><img src='/images/rb-b-help.png' style='display:none; position: absolute; top:77px; left:150px; z-index:99;'></div>
```

This is my Javascript

```
function HelpToggle($this) {
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"+$this).fadeToggle(500);
});
```

}

Any good ideas why this does not work?

No errors in the JavaConsole...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the previous answer was completely wrong.

In your case the `img` inside `#rb-b-help` is hidden, so you need to toggle that element

```
function HelpToggle($this) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#" + $this).find('img').fadeToggle(500);
    });
}
```

```js
function HelpToggle($this) {
  $("#" + $this).find('img').fadeToggle(500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/64X16&text=guideknap" style="position: absolute; top:285px; left:83px; z-index:1;" name="rb-b-help" onclick="HelpToggle(this.name)">
<div id='rb-b-help'>
  <img src='//placehold.it/64X16&text=rb-b-help' style='display:none; position: absolute; top:77px; left:150px; z-index:99;' />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the below code will work:

```
function HelpToggle($this) {
   $("#" + $this).fadeToggle(500);
}
```

Comment: Provide some explanaion to your answer please.